# FB API Request/notifications

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Have seen various articles dotted about with similar material on FB request invites. How is it possible these days to invite friends to an external website rather than a canvas app or game.

I have the necessary usernames and IDs from the graph API.

I need to loop these in PHP and send out an invitation to join/notification or even wall post. whichever is possible.

At the moment am using:

```
$apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    "/apprequests?ids=USERID,USERID,USERID" .
    "&message='INSERT_UT8_STRING_MSG'" . 
    "&data='INSERT_STRING_DATA'&"  .   
    $app_access_token . "&method=post";
```

which responds:

```
{
  "request":"229582530550300",
  "to":["USERID"]
}
```

This is correct according to FB but nothing appears on FB.

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, I think you can use the [Request Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)- since the case : user-friends seems to make more sense.

Direct URL to invoke the dialog:

> `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=<APP-ID>&message=<message>&redirect_uri=<uri-to-web-app>&to=<friends-ID-1>,<friend-id-2>...`

Now, there are two cases:

1. the app is a web-app,
2. the app is a canvas app

In both the cases, the **request** will be appear on the [App Centre](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests)

But, the **notification** will not appear if the app is a web app.

Comment: So it seems the current way of doing this actually puts a notification into the App Center. But unless you are a FB developer your never going to go into app center and isnt an obious way to get there for a standard user?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests/#user_to_user):

> User-to-user requests are only available for Canvas apps, not
>   websites, as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas
>   Page URL of the app that sent the request.

What you are trying to do seems to be impossible.